# Пришел с театра или пришел из театра"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: "пришел с театра или пришел из театра"?

Answer (score 2):

"Пришел из театра".  Конструкции "пошёл на театр", "пришёл с театра" использовались, если не ошибаюсь, до середины XIX века сначала как единственно возможные, потом - наряду с современными "в театр" и "из театра". Сейчас считаются устаревшими.
При этом в некоторых значениях и сочетаниях использование предлогов сохраняется: "[сообщение] с театра военных действий".

Кроме того, можно отметить, что в разговорной речи предлог "С" все чаще вытесняет "ИЗ" в сочетании с самыми разными существительными ("со школы", "с зоопарка", "с гостиницы"), хотя нормативным это пока не является.

Comment: Т.е. сначала было нормой, потом устарело, а теперь возвращается?

Comment: >Т.е. сначала было нормой, потом устарело, 
Да. Применительно только к театру и еще некоторым подобным словам.

>а теперь возвращается?
Нет. наблюдается частое **неправильное** использование только одного предлога из пары "В"-"ИЗ": т.е. замена "ИЗ" на "С", причем повсеместная, не связанная с конкретными словами: "со школы", "с зоопарка", "с гостиницы", "[сошел] с автобуса" (вместо правильного "из школы", "из зоопарка", "из гостиницы", "[вышел] из автобуса" ) - но никогда не "на школу", "на зоопарк", "[взошел] на автобус". 
Это не "возвращение", это совсем другое явление.

Answer (score 2):

"Пришёл с театра" в современном языке – это разговорное.  В некоторых случаях в выборе предлога отражается влияние народного языка, профессионального употребления и т.д.: работает в фотостудии , вышел из фотостудии – фильм дублирован на киностудии , ушёл с киностудии (профессиональный оборот, под влиянием сочетания на кинофабрике: работает на радио, на телевидении, вернулся с телевидения); Я побежал в кухню… (Горький).Вышел из кухни. – Нянька приходила на кухню… (Короленко). Уходила с кухни. (второй вариант под влиянием народной речи).

При названиях зрелищных организаций и мероприятий в литературном языке  установилось такое употребление: в театре, в кино, в цирке –из театра, из кино, из цирка (имеется в виду помещение), на концерте, на опере, на спектакле – вернулся с концерта,  с оперы, со спектакля (имеется в виду исполнение, представление). В профессиональном употреблении встречаются сочетания: работает на театре, снят с театра(имеется в виду не помещение, а деятельность), занят в концерте (как"служит на флоте"). Когда в 18 веке слово пришло в русский язык, оно обозначало "место для зрелищ", касалось не только помещений, но и открытой местности, поэтому говорили: "Пошёл на театр, вернулся с театра". Параллельно было значение театр как вид искусства, тоже употреблялось с предлогами "на"-"с"
Есть ещё омоним « театр »-театр военных действий – местность, где проходят военные действия – неограниченное пространство, поэтому на театр – с театра.

Answer (score 1):

Пришел с театра - это значит пришел с крыши театра. Согласитесь, это чушь. Поэтому правильно - "пришел из театра", так же как "пришел из школы"

Answer (score 1):

Предлогу В соответствует предлог ИЗ, а предлогу НА - С. Распространенная ошибка - пришел со школы вместо из школы.